# Getting specific COM server instance

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ole

Say I have multiple .exe files that register COM IClassFactories for a certain IID through `CoRegisterClassObject` function and specify `REGCLS_MULTI_SEPARATE` flag in the `flags` parameter.

Is there a way for a client trying to get an instance of the exposed interface to specify what process I want it to get that instance from? So far in my experiments when I was calling `CoCreateInstance` it was giving me a pointer to an instance from the longest running LocalServer exposing the requested interface.

Comment: Just curious: why do you need it for?

Comment: I have a couple of native processes and I want to have an RPC-style communication protocol with managed clients. COM so far seems like the most realistic approach.

Comment: Not with CoCreateInstance.  Look at IRunningObjectTable.

Comment: Do the .exe's register different CLSID values?  If so, then CoCreateInstance() handles that just fine.  Or are you running multiple copies of the same .exe so the same CLSID is being used?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I'm running multiple copies of the same .exe.

Comment: Hans, the running objects table approach worked for me! Thank you. If you'd go ahead and answer this question, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer.